# create pixelate background with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

How would one create such pixelated background using CSS and HTML?
[image]

This is the starter template:

```
<div class="pixelate"></div>

.pixelate{
  background-color: #93856e;
  width:300px;
  height:50px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WOyQVq

Comment: CSS has no such feature `background: #93856e pixelatePlease` , Why can't you create an image and set as repeated background image?

Comment: 2 ways. 1st : https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/i/image-rendering/. 2nd array of small div (low perf)

Comment: I would like to resize it in all directions with user gestures.

Comment: resize? I don't get your idea. Resize the DIV, not the background. The background will repeat. You wnt to scale the background? than use `background-size` property. But than your question makes still no sense after your comment.

Comment: exactly, if you set background-reapeat to repeat, it's going to be just fine.

Comment: oh, thanks guys. You are awasome

Comment: So yeah, like: `background: url(images/pixels.png) 50% 50%; background-size: 150%;` and make sure to read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: you could use gradient to create patterns : you can inspire yourself from https://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/  https://24ways.org/2011/css3-patterns-explained/

Comment: That CodePen link is wrong... You used _that_ link on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44911805/change-resize-icon-of-an-element-with-resize-style-applied/44911894?noredirect=1#comment76800290_44911894)