# change resize icon of an element with resize style applied

Tags: html, css

How do you change resize icon of an element with resize style applied?

for example:

```
.resize{
  background-color:red;
  width:300px;
  height:220px;
  resize:horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WOyQVq

See those 2 black lines at the bottom right? How do you change that icon?

Comment: Change it to what?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to change that controller symbol. In your case, I can suggest this solution. Add background color red and it will disappear

```
.resize::-webkit-resizer {
background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I believe that webkit has dropped support of this feature since this was posted.